# How to only log when in debug mode using erlang-lager?

Tags: erlang, log4j, lager

In Java Development, we did debug checking before logging a time / memory consuming operation.

for example:

```
if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
   log.debug("This is time / memory consuming {}", bigString);
}
```

with Erlang Lager, Do I need to do the same check before logging it?

If yes, how to check this?

Answer (score 1):

With lager, you can change desired log level with lager configuration, so you can omit any check in the code. If debug level is not enabled for any backend, it will be just dropped

See [example](https://github.com/basho/lager#configuration)

```
{lager, [
  {log_root, "/var/log/hello"},
  {handlers, [
    {lager_console_backend, info},
    {lager_file_backend, [{file, "error.log"}, {level, error}]},
    {lager_file_backend, [{file, "console.log"}, {level, info}]}
    {lager_file_backend, [{file, "debug.log"}, {level, debug}]}
  ]}
]}.
```

So debug logs will only go to `debug.log`

Comment: Thanks. I know this. with Java, if the message was time / memory consuming, I should  check it before put it into the log.    I wonder if I should do the same to Lager?

Comment: In lager, if the log is at the level that is not being printed then the logging is not called, it becomes an empty operation. Lager uses Erlang's parse_transform to replace all logging calls with some specific code. However, it may be different if the call is performed before the log is called, i.e. in the same line. Best to check it empirically. If you need to disable any piece of code then you can just use a compilation macro, which you pass to the compile as `d` option (or `-D` when calling `erlc` from shell).